# Raspberry pi 3B+ RCA noisy video output

Tags: raspbian, display, video, composite-video

I am working on a project in which I would like to connect my RPI to an old CRT TV, For this, I am using a 3.5mm to RCA composite cable. But when I connect my raspberry pi and TV the output on so noisy that it is useless. I think there is some kind of noise present in this channel. P.S. the TV is working fine there is no issue with the TV, and also I edited the config.txt as per requirement

Comment: `edited the config.txt as per requirement` - please share ... perhaps your cable is crap, are you using a TRRS or TRS connector?

Comment: TRRS commenting hdmi_force_hotplug and uncommenting sdtv_mode and sdtv_aspect.

Comment: Have you tested you have the correct TRRS cable https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack Is your TV PAL or NTSC ?

Comment: I tried both NTSC and pal mode, but the output is same noisy pi desktop. Also, when I modify sdtv_mode value in config.txt it became empty???????